# Find the exact value of a function given that $\sin u =-\frac{12}{13}$ and $\cos v= -\frac{21}{29}$ (both are in quadrant $3$)$\tan(u-v)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the exact value of a trigonometric function given that $\sin u =-\frac{12}{13}$ and $\cos v= -\frac{21}{29}$ (both are in quadrant $3$)

$\tan(u-v)$

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! What are your thoughts on the question and what work have you done so far? When you have a minute, please take the [tour of the site](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) 
and look at [how to format mathematics here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on Math SE. Furthermore, I suggest 
that you bookmark this [very useful MathJax page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 
for quick reference. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sin u = \frac{-12}{13} $ , $\cos u = \frac{-5}{13}$ and $\tan u = \frac{12}{5}$

$\cos v = \frac{-21}{29} $ , $\sin u = \frac{-20}{29}$ and $\tan u = \frac{20}{21}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\tan(u-v) = \frac{\tan u -\tan v}{1+\tan u \tan v}=\frac{\frac{12}{5} -\frac{20}{21}}{1+\frac{12}{5} \frac{20}{21}}= \color{red}{\frac{152}{345}}
\end{eqnarray*}